# Executing Shell script commands sequentially

Tags: shell-script, shell, ksh

My script (.ksh) :

```
cmd1 & cmd2
```

I want `cmd1` to be executed in the background and `cmd2` to start executing only after `cmd1` has started. But, when I run my script, `cmd2` is starting before `cmd1`, thereby causing me a problem.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Have a look [this answer on AU](https://askubuntu.com/a/538900/283843) also.

Answer (score 2):

By using the conditional operator `&&` you can force the "finish" of one execution before the other one starts. (I put "finish" in quotes, because what is actually "finishing" is putting the process in the background.)

While

```
$ (echo "foo" &) ; echo "bar"
```

might output

```
bar
foo
```

the following

```
$ (echo "foo" &) && echo "bar"
```

will output

```
foo
bar
```

because the shell needs to determine the exit status of the first command before it can execute the second.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would to add a tiny `sleep`:

```
cmd1 & sleep 1 && cmd2
```

More robust would be to use a wrapper for `cmd2` that makes sure the `cmd1` is actually running and then proceed.

Something like:

```
while ! pgrep cmd1; do
    sleep 1
done
cmd2
```

`while !` can be replaced with `until` BTW.

Comment: Dont we need an "&" after cmd1 so as it run it in the background?

Comment: @RaviTeja i presume you meant the second one. This goes as a wrapper for `cmd2`. You need to create a script with this, and it will run `cmd2` only when `cmd1` is running.